In Postgres, does percentile_disc reuse calculations from other percentile_disc in the same query?
Lets say you have some table you're querying percentiles from, with the same grouping used for both columns:
SELECT percentile_disc(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col) as p25,
       percentile_disc(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col) as p75 from my_table

Does Postgres reuse the grouping calculated for the first column when calculating the second?

It does. You can see that in explain analyse verbose:  no matter how many of those you add, you only loop once.
demo at db<>fiddle
explain analyse verbose
SELECT percentile_disc(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col) as p25
      ,percentile_disc(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col) as p75
      ,percentile_disc(0.3) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col) as p
    ,percentile_disc(0.4) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col)
    ,percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col)
    ,percentile_disc(0.6) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col)
    ,percentile_disc(0.7) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col)
from my_table;









Aggregate  (cost=8464.74..8464.75 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=343.493..343.495 rows=1 loops=1)


Output: percentile_disc('0.25'::double precision) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col), percentile_disc('0.75'::double precision) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col), percentile_disc('0.3'::double precision) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col), percentile_disc('0.4'::double precision) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col), percentile_disc('0.5'::double precision) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col), percentile_disc('0.6'::double precision) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col), percentile_disc('0.7'::double precision) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_col)


->  Seq Scan on public.my_table  (cost=0.00..7214.38 rows=500138 width=8) (actual time=0.016..39.669 rows=500000 loops=1)


Output: my_col


Planning Time: 0.122 ms


Execution Time: 344.358 ms



It also seems like it doesn't really matter how many of those you request. In this test I didn't see any clear correlation between exec time and the number of different percentile_disc() calls in the query. It ran 600 queries against a table with 100k rows, requesting 1-301 different, random percentiles. Those that asked for single percentile averaged around 32ms, same as those requesting 131 or 81 different percentiles.
Whatever differences I saw initially must've been just noise.

How does exec time go up as a function of input size N, and number of reusable queries Q? I'd guess O(IDX(column)+Q), where IDX(column) is something like NlogN?

@ijustlovemath Check out the test I added in the edit: that exec time going up must've been noise. It looks like it doesn't really matter after all how many you request, of course within reason (even though I tested queries even a bit beyond reason, asking for 301 different percentiles).
